# Why ADB push doesn't push if slash is path end?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I try to push a photo to my phone from my windows 10 pc using ADB.

The command I try is:

```
adb push C:\Users\Tim\PycharmProjects\project1\photoname.jpg /sdcard/photos/
```

The output is this:

```
C:\Users\Tim\PycharmProjects\project1\photoname.jpg: 1 file pushed. 16.3 MB/s (370030 bytes in 0.022s)
```

So I guess that means that the push was succesfull but when I check my phone the is no .jpg named photoname on my phone.
Does anyone know how to fix  this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adb push C:\Users\Tim\PycharmProjects\project1\photoname.jpg /sdcard/photos

try removing  slash from photo